# Controlling target redirect page from authorize endpoint

Tags: identityserver4

I'm migrating from Identity Server 3 and I have a question regarding controlling what page is redirected when we need to redirect from the authorize endpoint into the account controller.

The current solution using the PreAuthenticateAsync method on the UserService to look for a custom acr_value key/value in combination with prompt=login on the authorize request.

An example use case is allowing a deep link into the Register page, or into the Manage profile page if the user is logged in.

I cannot find a simple hook for controlling where we go after IDSrvr4 detects a login redirect.

I have found the IAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator interface and was wondering if a custom implementation ( or override the default behaviour of one of the ProcessXXXAsync methods from IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator ) is appropriate, but this feels like a sledgehammer approach.

The QuickStart scenario #6 from the IdSrv github repo is a close example of what I want to accomplish if you tried redirect to Register, or the Manage controller if logged in

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the page you want to go to for unauthenticated users like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options => options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/account/login");
```

For sending authenticated users back to that page you need to to implement `IAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator` - or rather derive from the default one.

Comment: thanks.  Is there a IdSrvr3 to IdSrvr4 migration guide floating around on the interwebs that you're aware of ?

Comment: Ok, found a further issue with this generator.  It appears impossible to change the url by overriding the ProcessLoginAsync.  Raised issue in repo for further discussion